# How do I upgrade a rails 4.1 app from ruby 1.9.3 to ruby 2.1.5 without using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3

I'm told to update my rails project from ruby version 1.9.3 to 2.1.5 but I don't know how

[image: 2.1.5 is my ruby version]

I updated my gem file to reflect 2.1.5, and then tried bundle install again, it seemed to work mostly...

Then I tried rake db:migrate and it couldn't handle it. so I don't think I "updated correctly"

[image]

I don't have RVM so I didn't know what to do with [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505339/how-do-i-upgrade-a-rails-3-2-app-from-ruby-1-9-3-to-ruby-2-1-5-using-rvm)

Can someone please help me update my code or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on Windows? Check out Ruby installer here: http://rubyinstaller.org/. Should be able to update Ruby that way.

Comment: yeah it did, I simply moved my rails installer version back to 1.9.3 instead of moving my project version up to ruby 2